# RestEasyClientBuild register ResteasyJackson2Provider - WARN about duplicate

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I am using the `org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder` to build a REST client in the following way:

```
ResteasyClient client = (new ResteasyClientBuilder())
    .maxPooledPerRoute(5)
    .connectionPoolSize(10)
    .socketTimeout(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .register(jacksonProvider)
    .register(new RestClientLogger())
    .register(new RestClientMDCFilter())
    .build();
```

The `jacksonProvider` that is registered there is a `ResteasyJackson2Provider jacksonProvider = new ResteasyJackson2Provider();` which comes with a custom `ObjectMapper` that is important for deserialization. So far so good, the problem is, that I get the following warning in JBoss:

```
10:31:38,414 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default-threads - 1) RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
```

This makes sense if I check the documentation when there already has been an instance of the same class that has been registered before. I used a decompiler to check what `ResteasyClientBuilder` is doing and was able to see, that it scans the classpath for jars that contain a resource that describes what "built in" providers should be registered.

One of the jboss provided implementations is now apparently already defining a `ResteasyJackson2Provider` that is registered there making it impossible for me to later register my own instance of it.

What are my options here? I need to get my version of the `ResteasyJackson2Provider` - or at least the `ObjectMapper`into the client. Can I somehow replace the existing one?

Comment: Relevant info for posterity: priority seems to play no part for a `ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>`, whether it's passed to `#register` or specified as `@Priority` on the implementing class. If you debug a call to `ResteasyProviderFactory#getContextResolver` during a client invocation, you can see that simply the first resolver in the list wins. (RESTEasy 3.6.2.Final.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same issue, but I did not want to remove the `resteasy-jackson2-provider` dependencies because we added that dependency explicitly for other parts of the system (using undertow, not full AS).

Turns out you can just extend the `org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider` without adding/overriding anything so you can register it with a higher priority than the default `org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider` picked up from the classpath (which is registered without a priority). This way you ensure your `ResteasyJackson2Provider` will be chosen over the one picked up via classpath scanning.

Extending to a "custom" `ResteasyJackson2Provider`:

```
public class CustomResteasyJackson2Provider extends ResteasyJackson2Provider {
}
```

Plug that in to the ResteasyClientBuilder with your customized ObjectMapper:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
// customize your objectMapper here...
CustomResteasyJackson2Provider jacksonProvider = new CustomResteasyJackson2Provider();
jacksonProvider.setMapper(objectMapper); // add objectMapper to provider

// register provider to client
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
     .register(jacksonProvider, 100) // any priority over 0 will do
     .build();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @user667 Thank you for the suggested edit to update to the newer package structure of the current jackson version!

Comment: If you annotate the custom provider with `@javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider` and `@javax.annotation.Priority(javax.ws.rs.Priorities#USER - 1)` as well as the `javax.ws.rs.Consumes` and/or `javax.ws.rs.Produces` as required, plus you register the class in the SPI `META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers` it works too! You don't have to add it to the rest client builder itself.

Comment: @dforce You are right, but that would then be picked up globally. At least in my usecase I  needed to provided a different ObjectMapper config for a specific ResteasyClient without interfering with either the configs of other ResteasyClients or the settings for the RestEndpoints we provide ourselves in the same deployment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your own packaged 'resteasy-jackson2-provider' jars, then one of the ways you can skip loading the resteasy provider provided my JBoss by excluding the below dependencies using the jboss-deployment-structure.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```